# My app keeps 2 TextViews on 1 line when the text gets longer

Tags: android, textview

[image: keep 2 TextViews in a line without losing characters of 1 textview]

I tried using `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` (because they are what I usually use) but I haven't got the desired results.
I want the first `TextView` to remain intact. What I mean is showing full "first `textview`" - not first text...(cutted text) or even losing all the text.

Update: The first textview should stick to the second textview when the second textview is shorter. But when the second textview is longer, the first textview will not be lost.

Here is the code of my **XML layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="second textviewwwwwwwww"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/second_textview"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="first textview"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why dont you set weight for textviews using linearlayout

Comment: I want the first textview to stick to the second textview when the second textview is shorter. But when the second textview is longer, the first textview will not be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/second_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first_textview"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="second textviewwwwwwwww"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="first textview"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Comment: not work for me. The second textview is lost when it gets longer.

Comment: try to increase maxLines

Answer (score 0):

You should try [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with `android:layout_weight`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="first textview"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="second tadkfj adfkj adflkja adfkj"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this does not make the first TextView to stick to the second TextView. What I want is the first TextView to follow the second TextView when it is shorter, But when the second TextView is longer, the first TextView will not be lost.

Comment: first TextView will not be lost if second textView gets longer

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is horizontal `LinearLayout`. first element's width should be set as `"wrap_content"` and the second one `"match_parent"`. also set `singleLine` attribute to `true` for the second element. So, your codes will be like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="first textview"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="second textviewwwwwwwww"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```